# When Should one use style: TextStyle() and Theme.of()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning Flutter. Sometimes I see coders use

```
text: Text("text", style: TextStyle(color: kTextColor)
```

and sometimes they use

```
child: Text("text",
  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
```

What is the difference between these two code snippets? And what does `context` mean?

Comment: Checkout this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion: in a big project it's good practice to define your *theme* first. *Then*, you implement it in your app. Therefore, I'd go with the second approach to define headlines and body texts and button texts.

Instead, when you want to personalize some text in your app a little you can use:

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copywith(
   // personalize even more, with exact the same properties of TextStyle
   ...
)
```

which copies everything in that `textTheme` besides the stuff you define in that block.

OF COURSE it makes sense to use `TextStyle` in some contexts, like when you want to quickly format some text that you know that it doesn't need refactoring at the moment you're writing it, i.e. you just want to style some text regardless of theming.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `MainApp()`, that used by main method. You can find something like this,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
        textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
              headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 33, color: Colors.orange),
              headline2: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
                color: Colors.pink,
              ),
            ),
      ),
      home: DropDOOO(),
    );
  }
```

So you can see there is a parameter call `ThemeData`. This will be used by default and when you will call `Theme.of()`. You can find `textTheme` here too.

Next one `TextStyle()`, you can override Texttheme using **TextStyle()** using it.

For more, visit

- [themes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes)
- [TextTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html)